# How to iterate through an array in the callback function of _.filter using Lo-dash

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, lodash

So I got some tricky stuff here. I have a JSON object which needs to be filtered based on a user query. In this JSON, I want to filter out the `category_of_foods` field which is an array of foods.

`breakfastItems =`

```
[
{
    "id": 338,
    "created_at": "2014-10-08T03:32:49.000Z",
    "user_id": 91,
    "type_of_meal": "breakfast",
    "category_of_foods": [
        "cheese burger",
        "fruit"
    ]
},
{
    "id": 339,
    "created_at": "2014-10-08T03:34:43.000Z",
    "user_id": 91,
    "type_of_meal": "breakfast",
    "category_of_foods": [
        "chicken burger",
        "fruit"
    ]
}
]
```

Using [Lo-Dash library](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) , I was able to make my code work when the `category_of_foods` field was just a string, not an array. I now have the following code which does not return matches:

```
$scope.showPicturesBreakfast = function(type, term){ // term = "fruit"
    function filterBreakfast(category, list){
        return _.filter(list, function(element){
            return _(element.category_of_foods).forEach( function(entry){
                return entry === category; // returns true twice if term is fruit
            });
        });
    }
    $scope.breakfastPictures = filterBreakfast(term, breakfastItems);
};
```

The code seems logical to me, as it was similar to before, except now I am also iterating through an array to find true matches to return to the `_.filter` function. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return a truthy or falsy value to the caller, `filter` in this case. Try using `some` instead, which returns a boolean:

```
return _(element.category_of_foods).some(function(entry){
    return entry === category;
```

It will return `true` if at least one entry matches.